# Print correct tabspaces with dictionaries in VScode Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, dictionary, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to print a python dictionary in VScode Jupyter Notebooks in the following style

```
foo:                       0
bar:                       1
foobar:                    99
long_word:                 photosynthesis
n_coeffs:                  6
```

regardless of the size of the key?

Trying this

```
dict = {"foo": 0, "bar": 1, "foobar": 99, "long_word": "photosynthesis", "n_coeffs": 6}

for key, value in dict.items():
    print('{:<20}{:<20}'.format(key,value)) # code by Tal Folkman, see answers
```

results in the **vscode builtin notebook output renderer** as

```
foo:                        0
bar:                        1
foobar:                     99
long_word:                  photosynthesis
n_coeffs:               6
```

Or other variants of mis-alignements. When copy-pasting the output to an editor, the spaces are correct, but the renderer does not conform to that. Is there a way to configure the builtin renderer to display all spaces?

Comment: "4 because a tab is 4 white spaces long" - not on the terminal I'm currently using. So, that depends on where you print your output.

Comment: get maximum key length for each keys. get maximum key length. add one more tab from maximum tabs. I will add answer, if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use a format string to set the columns to a minimum of 30 characters and align text to left:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
   print("{: <30} {: <30} ".format(*[key,value ]))
```

[Example from my python notebook I have just tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y5yS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening here is that it's taking the space after the end of the last character of key hence unequal spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {"foo": 0, "bar": 1, "foobar": 99, "long_word": "photosynthesis", "n_coeffs": 6}

n=max([int(len(key)/4) for key, value in dict.items()])
for key, value in dict.items():
    k=int(len(key)/4)
    print(key+'\t'+(n-k)*'\t'+str(value))
```

if you want colon additionally use like below,

```
dict = {"foo": 0, "bar1": 1, "foobar": 99, "long_word": "photosynthesis", "n_coeffs": 6}
n=max([int(len(key+':')/4) for key, value in dict.items()])
for key, value in dict.items():
    print(key+':'+'\t'+(n-int(len(key+':')/4))*'\t'+str(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to use indentation you can use `print('{:<20}{:<20}'.format())`:

```
dict = {"foo": 0, "bar": 1, "foobar": 99, "long_word": "photosynthesis", "n_coeffs": 6}

for key, value in dict.items():
    print('{:<20}{:<20}'.format(key,value))

#output:

foo                 0                   
bar                 1                   
foobar              99                  
long_word           photosynthesis      
n_coeffs            6
```

Comment: When i copy-paste the result into an editor, it works. However it still appears non-aligned in the rendered output. I will edit the question accordingly